# Azure Event Hubs: Kafka Consumer polls nothing in java

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to Read messages in my consumer from azure event-hub

this is my consumer configurations:

```
private final KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> consumer;
private final String topic;

public SampleConsumer(String topic) throws IOException {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileReader("src/main/resources/consumer.config"));
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
    "MyNamespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "GROUP_ID");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
this.topic = topic;
}
```

and this is my consumer.config file:

```
bootstrap.servers=<MyNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="$**********" password="*******";
```

and finally in this method I try to read the records:

```
@Override
public void doWork() {
  consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));
  ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
  System.out.println(records.count());
  for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {
    System.out.println("Received message: (" + record.value());
  }
}
```

It connect correctly to the azure and event-hub.
It then tries to read the records but every time it returns 0 without any error messages. I searched on the internet and I used a lot of different solutions but nothing worked so far. There should be at least some records in event-hub.

[image]

Could someone please help me to figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actively producing records? If not, then maybe you should consume from the beginning of the topic by setting `auto.offset.reset=earliest` for a new group id

The default behavior is to start at the end of the topic and poll new events *after* the consumer starts

Comment: thank you for answer but this was not the problem! I forgot to add it here but still the program doesn't work

Comment: Well, your client is clearly connecting to the cluster, so is the topic just empty? If you describe the consumer group, what information do you get?

Comment: I could finally find the issue! it was from the server side not the program so now the program works perfectly

Comment: What specifically was the issue?